# Game Center iOS 10 Invitation: "Retrieving..." message shown, but nothing happens

Tags: ios, game-center, ios10

I am building a game with 2 player peer to peer multiplayer over game center.

I use GKLocalPlayerListener delegate protocol to listen for invitation events:

```
-(void)player:(GKPlayer *)player didAcceptInvite:(GKInvite *)invite
```

For testing i have 2 iOS 10 devices with my personal Apple ID, but 2 different Game Center accounts logged in. The invitation is an icloud-link which appears in the iMessage App as a Game Center invitation. When i tap the link, a message "Retrieving..." appears, after a few seconds it disappears and nothing happens.
This is the first Problem, do you know if it happens because i use the same Apple ID on both devices and 2 different gamecenter accounts?

I also tested with an iOS 9 device. When i send the invitation from iOS 9 to iOS 10, a push notification appears and the above method is successfully called.

If i send the invitation from iOS 10 to iOS 9, the link appears in iMessage as an icloud.com link and redirects to the icloud website showing an "Untitled" item. How can i implement it the right way?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You have to have two **different iCloud** accounts to fix "Retrieving..." issue .  I had the same issue and fixed it soon as i changed my iCloud account